# Paypal button with custom field

Tags: button, paypal, paypal-buttons

I created a button like this:
[image]

I have a text field but in my test transaction I was not able to undestand where can I see this info in the payment.

Is the only way to collect this data to activate the option
'Can your customer add special instructions in a message to you?' ?

Answer (score 0):

The "special instructions in a message to you" is a legacy PayPal checkout thing that not shown during checkouts anymore, so that won't actually matter whether you ahve it enabled or not.

The "Add text field" you have enabled in the above will show the entered value in the regular Transaction Details screen, and in reports or activity downloads that have enabled the option to show shopping cart or line item details (this is a checkbox when generating certain activity download reports)